# how to debug memory overwriting on linux

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory-management

I met a issue. The value of pointer was modified and the pointer pointed to a address which can't be accessed.  BTW, the address of pointer is on heap.
I'm wondering is there any way to set the pointer read-only after it's initialized, and when someone try to change the value of pointer, the process will crash.

Thanks.
Jerry

Answer (score 2):

You can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to detect invalid pointer access as well as many other invalid memory usages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mprotect`, but I would advise against modifying heap pages since those are managed my `libc`.

```
 mprotect(page_aligned_address, len, PROT_READ);
```

If you intend to use that I recommend you allocate your memory using `mmap` in order not to mess up your heap.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. where is the memory alloced by mmap from, heap?

Comment: @user3090584 `mmap` allocates memory directly from the System somewhere in your virtual memory. In fact `malloc` calls `mmap` itself to get memory from the system, it just manages those pages differently. The part of your VM that is managed by `malloc` and family is called the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to generate map file in your terminal window in Linux :

```
gcc -o demo -Wl,-Map,demo.map demo.c
```

You can easily find out where your memory usage goes wrong or in which place the overwritting takes place. This map file will help you know about each section of the memory in detail.

Comment: Knowing where memory is laid out does not help one to debug why a variable is getting overwritten.